# UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user) returns random IDs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have asp net core 5 web api with EF Core and when I call for the second or more times to `userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user)` I get everytime a different ID. Please see below the comments in the code

My controller is similar to this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Registration([FromBody] UserForRegistrationDto userForRegistration)
{
    IdentityResult result = await _repository.Account.Create(userForRegistration);
    var host = $"{HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{HttpContext.Request.Host}";
    await _repository.Account.GenerateEmailConfirmation(host, userForRegistration);
    return StatusCode(201);
}
```

And a repository similar to this one:

```cs
public async Task<IdentityResult> Create(UserForRegistrationDto userForRegistration)
{
    var user = new User { UserName = userForRegistration.Email, Email = userForRegistration.Email };
    var user2 = new User { UserName = userForRegistration.Email, Email = userForRegistration.Email }; // For testing
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userForRegistration.Password);
    
    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user); // This ID is the same as in the DB, so it works fine
    var userId2 = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user2); // This ID now looks random, not in the DB, even using exactly same User data.
    
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Visitor");
    return result;
}
public async Task GenerateEmailConfirmation(string hostUrl, UserForRegistrationDto userForRegistration)
{
    var user = new User { UserName = userForRegistration.Email, Email = userForRegistration.Email };
    var user2 = new User { UserName = "blabla" };
    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user); //Again "random" ID
    var userId2 = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user2 ); //Doesn't exist in Db but I get a random ID anyways
    .....
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the `Id` property would be initialized to form a new GUID string value. For details, you can check [the source code of `IdentityUser` class](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b795ac3546eb3e2f47a01a64feb3020794ca33bb/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/IdentityUser.cs#L21), like below.

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="IdentityUser"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The Id property is initialized to form a new GUID string value.
/// </remarks>
public IdentityUser()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Besides, to get `Id` stored in DB of the specific user, you can try to modify the code as below.

```
public async Task GenerateEmailConfirmation(string hostUrl, UserForRegistrationDto userForRegistration)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userForRegistration.Email);

    var userId = user.Id;

    //.....
}
```

Comment: You are right. I was focusing so much in GetUserIdAsync that I didn't realize that the issue was in IdentityUser creating a new Id everytime you create an object!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you trying to search a user before you saved it to the database.
You need to save the user to the database first e.g. like this:

```
IdentityResult res = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userForRegistration, password);
```

then you can find it like this:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userForRegistration.UserName);
```

Comment: I'm using already CreateAsync and unfortunately the method needs to be `GetUserIdAsync` (the method was initially failing inside the AspNetCore.Identity library, which I just moved out to reproduce it in my code)

Comment: You need to load the User from the database. You could use var `userId = (await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userForRegistration.UserName)).Id`. `GetUserIdAsync` probably needs a user that is loaded from the db.